# Redefine libinput software button area

Tags: libinput

I'm trying to configure libinput to use about 1/3 of the height of the touchpad as the software button area rather than the roughly 1/5 of the height. 
Having only 1/5 of the height is quite small for me, since I usually have a finger ready to perform clicks on the bottom left of the trackpad and end up triggering the scroll functionality.

As reference I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 and libinput 1.10.4-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: not possible, libinput hardcodes the button sizes and there is no toggle to expose them (and no plans to expose toggles for this either). The button sizes do adjust themselves based on the touchpad size but they max out at 10mm height from the bottom edge.

Making them larger has implications on a lot of other things because the button zones are special (e.g. they suppress most pointer movement).

Comment: I thought so, but I still had hopes :).